# Highcharts and loading data via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, highcharts

Just getting started with Highcharts and hoping that the issue I'm encountering is something relatively simple/stupid that I'm missing.

I took the sample from the Highcharts live update demo  - http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

and modified just the series data piece to pull 'real' data:

Original code:

```
series: [{
    name: 'CPU utilization',
    data: (function () {
      // generate an array of random data
      var data = [],
        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
        i;
      for (i = -279; i <= 0; i++) {
        data.push({
          x: time + i * 1000,
          y: Math.random() * 10
        });
      }
      return data;
    })()
  }
]
```

Replaced with:

```
series: [{
    name: 'CPU utilization',
    data: (function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/api/data/query',
        data: query,
        content: "application/json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (point) {
          var vals = point.queries[0].results[0].values;
          var data = [],
            i;
          for (i = -vals.length + 1; i <= 0; i++) {
            data.push({
              x: vals[i + vals.length - 1][0],
              y: vals[i + vals.length - 1][1]
            });
          }
          return data;
        }
      });
    })()
  }
]
```

Data output format looks identical for random and real:

Random:

```
Array[280]
[0 … 99]
0: Object
x: 1365259804521
y: 9.2204492539
```

Real:

```
Array[280]
[0 … 99]
0: Object
x: 1365259979000
y: 3
```

However, when attempting to use the real data, I'm getting highcharts errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined highcharts.js:199
P.addPoint highcharts.js:199
$.ajax.success test2.html:265
c jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
p.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
k jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
r
```

Any suggestions on where to look? I'm sure its something that I'm doing as this has to be fairly routine.

Comment: This is a very long shot, but once I had problems with highcharts and AJAX if the URL didn't have a hashtag. No idea, why. Even though it's probably something different, try adding a `#` at the end of your URL.

Answer (score 0):

The 'data' is going out of scope, so the immediate function invocation is not returning any data. Declare the **var data** strong textoutside of the ajax invocation. Something like this:

```
(function() {
  var data = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: '/api/data/query',
    ...
    ...
})();
```

Comment: That makes sense - however, I've tried moving the data variable all  the way up the chain but the problem persists. I also set the ajax call to synchronous just in case it was a timing issue. FWIW, logging the series to the console shows that the random data has the full set of 280 data points, while the real data is incomplete: data: Array[0] compared to data: Array[280] - within the function, obviously both show the full 280 data points.

Comment: Ahh. I think we should invert the logic. Lets fetch the data first using Ajax call and in the success handler we should populate the series object.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what ended up working:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'CPU utilization',
        data: (function() {
                        var data;
                        $.ajax({
                        url: '/api/data/query',
                        data: query,
                        async: false,
                        content: "application/json",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(point) {
                        data =  point.queries[0].results[0].values;
                        }
                        });
            return data;
        })()
    }]
```

I suspect that the 'async: false' will not be needed if I move the data retrieval to its own   function?